# Does Mage Hand require line of sight to summon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips, line-of-sight

I've seen many questions asked about whether or not you need to be able to see your Mage Hand in order to control it.
However, can Mage Hand be summoned through a wall or other such obstruction?
Mage Hand's description states (PHB pg 256):

> A spectral, floating hand appears at a point you choose within range. The hand lasts for the duration or until you dismiss it as an action. The hand vanishes if it is ever more than 30 ft away from you or if you cast this spell again.

The part I'm interested in is "a point you choose within range".
So that brings me to my question: can you summon a mage hand at a point you cannot see? For example, on the other side of a wall or door; a point you know exists, but you simply cannot see from where you are.

Here's a hypothetical situation to hopefully help clarify my question. Say a caster needs to get into a room, but the door is locked. The caster wants to cast Mage Hand behind the door to then unlock it from the other side. Could they do that?

Comment: Related on [Can a spell be cast through semi-transparent things?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101206/can-a-spell-be-cast-through-semi-transparent-things) and [Can the *find familiar* spell resummon the familiar behind a barrier?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65485/can-the-find-familiar-spell-resummon-the-familiar-behind-a-barrier)

Comment: Welcome to our stack! Please take the [tour] to learn more about us and how we operate. Thanks and happy gaming!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### It doesn't require line of sight but it does require [a clear path to the target](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AClearPathtotheTarget)

As a spell, [Mage Hand](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mage-hand) must follow the general rules for spellcasting including:

> **A Clear Path to the Target**
>
> To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can't be behind total cover.

You can summon it at a point you cannot see but not if there is no clear line between you and that point. So, you can summon it at a point obscured by fog or if you were blindfolded, but you can't do it on the other side of a wall or door.

Once it is summoned, you can move it to a place you couldn't summon it providing there is some route to get there. To cast you need a direct line, to move it there the path can be labyrinthine.